I am stuck with BehaviorSubject in angular
I created centralized error handling service using BehaviorSubject in Angular v 17.It does not working in the expected way!
The problem areas are :
NotificationService -->  the centralized error handler.
NotificationComponent --> Reusable User Friendly Error and Progress message showing popup modal,i directly added it in my   Appcomponent.
Surrender Pet Component --> Where i try to use the Notification for showing option.
I thik those BhaviourSubjects not emitting the data the way i expected
NotificationService:
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';

    @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class NotificationService {
       successMessageSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string | null>(null);
       errorMessageSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string | null>(null);

       successMessageAction$ = this.successMessageSubject.asObservable();
       errorMessageAction$ = this.errorMessageSubject.asObservable();

       setSuccessMessage(message: string) {
       this.successMessageSubject.next(message);
     }

   setErrorMessage(message: string) {
   this.errorMessageSubject.next(message);
    console.log(this.errorMessageSubject.getValue());
   }

   clearSuccessMessage() {
    this.successMessageSubject.next(null);
    }

    clearErrorMessage() {
      this.errorMessageSubject.next(null);
    }

   clearAllMessages() {
    this.clearSuccessMessage();
    this.clearErrorMessage();
     }
    }


NotificationComponent :
import { Component, OnInit, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { NotificationService } from '../../../core/services/notifiaction/notification.service';
import { AsyncPipe, CommonModule, NgIf } from '@angular/common';
import { tap } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-notification',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgIf,AsyncPipe,CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './notification.component.html',
  styleUrl: './notification.component.scss',
 
})
export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit {
   
   private notificationService:NotificationService = inject(NotificationService);
   
  
   successMessage$ = this.notificationService.successMessageAction$.pipe(
     tap((message)=>{
      if(message){
      console.log('clicked')
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.notificationService.clearAllMessages()  
      },5000)
    }
     })
   )

   errorMessage$ = this.notificationService.errorMessageAction$.pipe(
    tap((message)=>{
      console.log(message);
      if(message){
     console.log('clicked')
     setTimeout(()=>{
       this.notificationService.clearAllMessages()  
     },5000)
    }
    })
  )


   ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("initialized")
  }
  }

Surrender Pet Component
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { ButtonComponent } from '../../../shared/components/button/button.component';
import { NgClass, NgIf, } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PetsAdopteService } from '../../../core/services/pets-adopte/pets-adopte.service';
import { SurrenderPet } from '../../../core/models/surrenderPet.model';
import { NotificationService } from '../../../core/services/notifiaction/notification.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-surrender-pet',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgClass,
    RouterLink,
    NgIf,
    ButtonComponent,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers:[PetsAdopteService,NotificationService],
  templateUrl: './surrender-pet.component.html',
  styleUrl: './surrender-pet.component.scss'
})
export class SurrenderPetComponent {

  private petAdopteService=inject(PetsAdopteService);
  private notificationService=inject(NotificationService);

  submitted:boolean = false;

  registerPet= new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl<string>('',[Validators.required]),
    phoneNo:new FormControl<string>('',[Validators.required]),
    petType:new FormControl<string> ('',[Validators.required]),
    location:new FormControl<string>('',[Validators.required]),
    otherDetails:new FormControl<string>('',[Validators.required])
  })

  onSubmit(){
      this.submitted = true;
      if(this.registerPet.valid){
       this.petAdopteService.sendPetSurrender_Request(this.registerPet.value as SurrenderPet).subscribe(
        {
          next:(data)=>{
         console.log(data);
        }
         
        }
       )
      }
  }
}


Notification Component html template:
<div class="z-40">
   <div class="z-40" *ngIf="successMessage$ | async as successMessage" id="toast-success" class=" fixed fixed bottom-5 right-5 flex items-center w-full max-w-xs p-4 mb-4 text-gray-500 bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:text-gray-400 dark:bg-gray-800" role="alert">
       <div class="inline-flex items-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 w-8 h-8 text-green-500 bg-green-100 rounded-lg dark:bg-green-800 dark:text-green-200">
           <svg class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
               <path d="M10 .5a9.5 9.5 0 1 0 9.5 9.5A9.51 9.51 0 0 0 10 .5Zm3.707 8.207-4 4a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 0l-2-2a1 1 0 0 1 1.414-1.414L9 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 1.414Z"/>
           </svg>
           <span class="sr-only">Success icon</span>
       </div>
       <div class="ms-3 text-sm font-normal">{{successMessage}}</div>
       <button type="button" class="ms-auto -mx-1.5 -my-1.5 bg-white text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-300 p-1.5 hover:bg-gray-100 inline-flex items-center justify-center h-8 w-8 dark:text-gray-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:bg-gray-700" data-dismiss-target="#toast-success" aria-label="Close">
           <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
           <svg class="w-3 h-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
               <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6"/>
           </svg>
       </button>
   </div>

   <div *ngIf="errorMessage$ | async as errorMessage" id="toast-failure" class=" fixed fixed bottom-5 right-5 flex items-center w-full max-w-xs p-4 mb-4 text-gray-500 bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:text-gray-400 dark:bg-gray-800" role="alert">
       <div class="inline-flex items-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 w-8 h-8 text-green-500 bg-green-100 rounded-lg dark:bg-green-800 dark:text-green-200">
           <svg class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
               <path d="M10 .5a9.5 9.5 0 1 0 9.5 9.5A9.51 9.51 0 0 0 10 .5Zm3.707 8.207-4 4a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 0l-2-2a1 1 0 0 1 1.414-1.414L9 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 1.414Z"/>
           </svg>
           <span class="sr-only">Success icon</span>
       </div>
       <div class="ms-3 text-sm font-normal">{{errorMessage}}</div>
       <button type="button" class="ms-auto -mx-1.5 -my-1.5 bg-white text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-300 p-1.5 hover:bg-gray-100 inline-flex items-center justify-center h-8 w-8 dark:text-gray-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:bg-gray-700" data-dismiss-target="#toast-success" aria-label="Close">
           <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
           <svg class="w-3 h-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
               <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6"/>
           </svg>
       </button>
   </div>
</div>
   



The PetsAdopteService where i called the setMessages functions!

    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Injectable, inject } from '@angular/core';
    import { EMPTY, Observable, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs';
    import { SurrenderPet } from '../../models/surrenderPet.model';
    import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment.development';
    import { petsSurrenderEndpoints } from '../../constants/APIEndPoints/petsAdopte.EndPoints';
    import { NotificationService } from '../notifiaction/notification.service';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class PetsAdopteService {

    constructor() { }

    private http:HttpClient=inject(HttpClient);
    private notificationService=inject(NotificationService);

    sendPetSurrender_Request(payload:SurrenderPet):Observable<SurrenderPet>{
     return this.http.post<SurrenderPet>                                                                              (environment.apiUrl+petsSurrenderEndpoints?.createSurrenderRequest,payload).pipe(
        tap((data)=>{
        this.notificationService.setSuccessMessage('Your request sent successfully')
      }),
      catchError((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
         this.notificationService.setErrorMessage("eROR");
         return EMPTY;
      })
     )
     }
    }



Is there any way to fix this problem with out choosing signal, because i want  to learn more about rxjs!

"I thik those BhaviourSubjects not emitting the data the way i expected" - please elaborate. What's the actual behavior and what's the expected behavior?

For example when the form is submitted from the client side, but got 500 error from server,it needs to trigger  clearErrorMessage() then the notification component needs to show the user friendly error

@BerlinJohns.M please share the html for notification component, if possible a stackblitz!

I added the html template of notification component in the question, i hope this is usefull for debugging!

maybe you can create a stackbliz

Okay, I finally found the solution. This strange behavior happened because I added services to the providers array of the standalone components. They were already provided at the root level. After I removed them, the logic worked correctly.
